# Is there a function in PHP akin to substr() for integers?

Tags: php, int, substr

I have a phone number which will be recorded as an int (e.g 1234512312345) on my database but which I would like to represent as (12345) 123 - 12345 on a webpage.  If it was a string I would use substr but it seems inelegant to convert it to a strval.

While I appreciate that integers and strings are categorically distinct, is there a means to do something to this effect without writing a less-than efficient function myself?

Comment: The delights of loose typing... substr() is the function you're looking for... why do you think it's inelegant casting it to a string? especially as you don't even need to use strval()

Comment: Why not just use substr, without all these musings? **Even** if it takes you "inelegant" manual type casting. An example of not a real question out of nowhere.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php

Comment: sincerely i would store them as a string, so you could avoid problems with plus symbols or leading 0's on the numbers, and as you won't wich phone number is "higher" than other and stuff like that (aritmethic operations or comparisons) you don't need to use int field, yes you will save some space, but really that much space?

Comment: if a phone number starts with a 0 wont the first digit be lost if you store it as an integer?

Comment: @PedrodelSol the first digits get 'lost' indeed but when printing you can put them back with formatting

Answer (score 11):

You can try [vprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php)  or  [vsprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) with [sscanf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

```
$data = 1234512312345;
vprintf("(%d)-%d-%d",sscanf($data, "%5d%3d%5d"));
```

[Output](http://eval.in/15469)

```
(12345)-123-12345
```

[Multiple PHP Version Test](http://3v4l.org/rMOOe)

***Note**

If you want to return it has a value then it should be

```
$var = vsprintf("(%d)-%d-%d",sscanf($data, "%5d%3d%5d"));
        ^
        |---- Note the `s`
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question, and seeing that OP *clearly doesn't want to convert to a string*.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Note: answering this because of the title, **treating phone numbers as integers is not a good idea**</sup>

You should **take advantage of PHP's type-juggling capabilities** and use string functions over you phone number, but if you want to do it **C** style and maintain working with integers you have:

- the **`/`** operator for **division**, helpful for getting the first digits (dividing `123` to `100` will give you the first digit, but not right away because `123/100=1.23`, using the `floor()` function will give you `floor(123/100)=1` but we might have a problem here also because `floor()`'s result is of type `float` and not `integer`)
- the **`%`** operator for **modulo**, helpful for getting the last digits (`123` modulo `10` will give you the last digit right away and of type integer, eg. `123%10=3`)

So you could extract the parts needed from your phone number like so (the integer way):

```
$last=$no%100000; // get last 5 digits (modulo by 1 followed by 5 zeroes)

$no=$no-$last; // subtract the last digits from original number

$no=$no/100000; // divide to shorten the number, end up with a natural number

$area=$no%1000; // get last 3 again

$prefix=($no-$area)/1000; //remainder is the first digits of the original number
```

or (the `float`/`double`/`real` way) - *just more readable*:

```
$last=$no%1e5; // scientific notation 1e5 = 10000 (1 followed by 5 zeroes)

$no=($no-$last)/1e5;

$area=$no%1e3;

$prefix=($no-$area)/1e3;
```

Live code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tVRjXC

*Note: scientific notation `e` uses type `float`*

You should also keep in mind the maximum integer on 32bit platforms is `2^31 = 2.147.483.648`

---

Now, using this code with a 'phone number' like `0077705501234` will give you headaches!

So it comes from the database, but if by any change it comes out as a real `int` PHP will interpret any `0` leading number in **[octal base](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)** and convert it to decimal internally so you'll end up with a totally different 'phone number', garbage to be exact.

If PHP receives it as a `string` and you really want to work with integers you could [type-cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it with `(int) $no` or convert with `$no+0` etc.

Anyway leading zeroes don't matter for integers, but do for strings so you might end up with  `77705501234` and you might want to do length checking (the <s>integer</s> float way):

*I'm going with float because there are to many zeroes to keep count on...*

We know the number must have `13` digits so we can check `if ( $no > 1e12 )` and maybe also `if ( $no < 1e14 )` for verification purposes.

If you want to also know the 'length' of the number (*you will need to know [pow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) for this*):

```
for ($i=1;$i<13;$i++) { //count from 1 to 12
    //stop when $no modulo 10^$i is the number
    if ( $no % pow(10,$i) == $no ) break; 
}
// number of digits of $no are stored in $i - equivalent to strlen()
```

And finally to print your number correctly even with missing leading zeroes integers:

`printf('Your number: (%05u) %03u - %05u',$prefix,$area,$last);`

Live code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xgr8RQ

*Side note: for big numbers you also have [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions but they work with strings*

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to store and treat phone numbers as integers, but simply as strings.

So convert your number to a string using `strval()`, then you can use `substr()` and all other string functions on it.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, but storing telephone numbers as strings is sensible advice as they often contain leading zeroes that get lost with any storage as numerics

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this code.

```
<?php
   $data = 1234512312345;
   echo "(".substr($data, 0, 5).") ".substr($data, 5, 3)."-".substr($data,8);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,,,

```
<?php
$phone = "1234512312345";
//(12345) 123 - 12345

$array = str_split($phone,5);
$array1 = substr($phone,5, 3);
$array2 = substr($phone,8, 5);

echo "(".$array[0].") ".$array1."-".$array2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it Only to show on WebPage?

If yes, You can use one jquery plugin to do this.

The bests for me:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/